# Best FUNCTION to Delete Dash in a string this example by sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i want to create function for delete dasht(3- , 2-)of interest in  this example :

**column:**

```
1GBDDR3-1066-21
2GBDDR3-1066-21
3- 4GBDDR3-1066-414
1GBDDR3-1066-21
2-1GBDDR3-1066-21
```

output:

```
1GBDDR3-1066-21
2GBDDR3-1066-21
4GBDDR3-1066-414
1GBDDR3-1066-21
1GBDDR3-1066-21
```

Comment: What about the space in the 3rd row?

Comment: Space is ther column now but trim do this.

Comment: @RedArmy SQL Server has `RTRIM` and `LTRIM`, which won't help you there. You'll need to use `REPLACE`

Comment: `replace (col,'3-','')`,used but in the cell is `ddr3-` and remove `3-` in this and output not correct for me. `4gbdddr1066`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `stuff()`:

```
select (case when col like '_-%' then stuff(col, 2, 1, '') else col
        end)
```

Note:  The question is explicitly about the dash, so I assume the space in the third row is a typo.

Comment: correct for remove dasht but 3 no ? please see outoput row 3 and 5.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `PATINDEX` with `RIGHT`, `LEN` and `LTRIM`:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save is this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    col varchar(30)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('1GBDDR3-1066-21'),
('2GBDDR3-1066-21'),
('3- 4GBDDR3-1066-414'),
('1GBDDR3-1066-21'),
('2-1GBDDR3-1066-21')
```

The query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PATINDEX('[0-9]-%', col) > 0 THEN
           LTRIM(RIGHT(col, LEN(col)-2))
       ELSE
          col
       END
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
1GBDDR3-1066-21
2GBDDR3-1066-21
4GBDDR3-1066-414
1GBDDR3-1066-21
1GBDDR3-1066-21
```

Answer (score 2):

For an alternative solution;

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    col varchar(30)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('1GBDDR3-1066-21'),
('2GBDDR3-1066-21'),
('3- 4GBDDR3-1066-414'),
('1GBDDR3-1066-21'),
('2-1GBDDR3-1066-21')

DECLARE @refValue NVARCHAR(7)='GBDDR3'
SELECT 
RIGHT((LEFT(col, CHARINDEX(@refValue,col)-1)),1) 
+@refValue
+RIGHT(col,LEN(col)-(CHARINDEX(@refValue,col) + LEN(@refValue))+1) FROM @T
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are only `GBDDR` in that table, then you can use:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(columnName,CHARINDEX('GB',columnName)-1,LEN(columnName))
FROM tableName
```

Or:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN LEN(columnName)-LEN(REPLACE(columnName,'-','')) > 2
            --if we got more than two dashes
            THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(columnName,CHARINDEX('-',columnName)+1,LEN(columnName))) 
            --take sub-string from first occurrence of dash+1 to the end of the string 
            ELSE columnName END 
            --else take the full string
FROM tableName
```

Output:

```
1GBDDR3-1066-21
2GBDDR3-1066-21
4GBDDR3-1066-414
1GBDDR3-1066-21
1GBDDR3-1066-21
```

Comment: @RedArmy my pleasure! :)